# In the Earth Engine Code Editor, how do you delay execution of ui.Map widget method until the map loads?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Trying to access a [ui.Map](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ui_widgets?hl=en#ui.map) method can result in a the following error message:

> Could not get scale. Map is not loaded yet.

The following code demonstrates this issue:

```js
var map = ui.Map();
ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(map);

map.onChangeBounds(function () {
  print('Try to use the onChangeBounds map event.', map.getScale());
});

map.onIdle(function () {
  print('Try with the onIdle map event.', map.getScale());
});

print('Try outside of a map event handler.', map.getScale());
```

where the response is:

```
Try outside of a map event handler.
Could not get scale. Map is not loaded yet.

Try to use the onChangeBounds map event.
Could not get scale. Map is not loaded yet.

Try with the onIdle map event.
Could not get scale. Map is not loaded yet.
```

Note that I was unable to trigger this issue with the Code Editor's default `Map` object.